# Making python sklearn probability estimate into indexed series

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, indexing, scikit-learn

I am working on making predicted probability of response (binary: yes or no (1, 0)) on 60,000 dispute claims each with its unique reference ID. Using the first 3/4 of the data as training set (X_train, y_train) with logistic regression as classifier to predict the response probability of the last 1/4 as test set (X_test), I would like to make the output into 60,000 indexed series, such that the output looks like

```css
reference_id
   184932    0.531842
   185362    0.401958
   185361    0.105928
   185338    0.018572
             ...
   276499    0.208567
   276500    0.818759
   269851    0.018528
   Name: response, dtype: float32
```

I implemented the following Python code:

```css
y_score_lr = LogisticRegression(C=10).fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
y_proba = y_score_lr
```

The result is an numpy array like this

```css
array([ 0.05225495,  0.00522493,  0.07369773, ...,  0.06994582, 0.06995239,  0.12659022])
```

which is an numpy array.

But I am not sure if this array actually matches the corresponding reference_id in the original X_test data frame, and I haven't figured out how to convert it into an indexed "series" like the one I mentioned at the beginning of this post.

It will be very appreciated if someone could point me to helpful shortcut to achieve this.

I also tried using

```css
y_score_lr = LogisticRegression(C=10).fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
y_proba = y_score_lr.tolist()
```

to convert the array into a list, but still could not make it into the desired series-type output with 'reference_id' indexed.

Thank you.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

First of all, yes, it matches the values of `X_test`: the first row corresponds to the first value in the `y_proba` array.

Secondly, there are several ways you can approach this problem.

One of the possible solutions may be the following, assuming you want `dtype=pandas.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

y_proba_indexed = pd.Series(
    data=y_proba, index=X_test['reference_id'], name='response', dtype=np.float32)

print(y_proba_indexed)
```

This would give you something like this:

```
84932     0.531842
185362    0.401958
185361    0.105928
185338    0.018572
      ....
276499    0.208567
276500    0.818759
269851    0.018528
Name: response, dtype: float32
```

To access, for instance, a probability referring to `reference_id = 185338` you may type: `y_proba_indexed.loc[[185338]]`, the output will be:

```
185338    0.018572
Name: respone, dtype: float32
```

---

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I am trying to get at. I especially appreciated that you clarified the match between the values of X_test and their counterparts in the y_proba array.
Thank you.